# Laravel hasMany relationship custom select result empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have tables, users, profiles, contacts. 1 user has 1 profile, 1 profile has many contacts, I want to get profile with filtered contact and selected column (I don't want get all column). I success with coding below

**UserController.php**

```
$profile = $user->with(['profile.emails', 'profile.phones'])->first();
```

**User.php**

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

**Profile.php**

```
public function emails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class)
        ->where('type', 'email');
}

public function phones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::class)
        ->where('type', 'phone');
}
```

result data like this

```
{
    "username": "user",
    "email": "user@mail.com",
    "profile": {
        "first_name": "Alex",
        "last_name": "Ariana",
        "emails": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "profile_id": 1,
                "type": "email",
                "prefix": "Personal",
                "value": "alex@mail.com",
                "is_primary": 0,
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "profile_id": 1,
                "type": "email",
                "prefix": "Business",
                "value": "business@mail.com",
                "is_primary": 1,
            }
        ],
        "phones": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "profile_id": 1,
                "type": "phone",
                "prefix": "45",
                "value": "564637345345",
                "is_primary": 1,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but then I add select on the relation like this

```
    public function emails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class)
            ->select([DB::raw('IFNULL(prefix, "Email") AS type'), 'value AS url', 'is_primary'])
            ->where('type', 'email');
    }

    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class)
            ->select(['prefix', 'value AS number', 'is_primary'])
            ->where('type', 'phone');
    }
```

then I got empty contact data like this
{

```
"id": 1,
"username": "user",
"email": "user@mail.com",
"profile": {
    "first_name": "Alex",
    "last_name": "Ariana",
    "emails": [ ],
    "phones": [ ]
}
```

}

Why this is happen?, if I access from user via `hasManyThrough` it works, but when I use `hasMany`, it result empty.

Comment: you have to select any foreign keys needed for the relationship, otherwise it can't match the children up with the parents, depending on the relationship you may need the 'id' field to be able to match the records up

Comment: ok but why in `hasManyThrough` does not show a problem,, the different is only relationship method

Comment: the foreign key, you need the foreign key that links those to their parent

Comment: Do you have custom selects in User's `profile()` relation? If yes, you should add `id` column to selects.

Comment: I added profile_id, and it works, thanks, but again when I use hasManyThrough access via user model, I can select only the column that I want (without profile_id or id), why?

Comment: look at the generated query/queries and you might see why